# Python loading 'utf-16' file can't decode '\u0153'

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a text file encoded as `utf-16` which throws an exception for the following character: `'\u0153'`.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0153' in position

I'm using a very simple script to load the file, and I also tried *ignoring* errors without avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16", errors='replace') as data_file:    
    print(data_file.read())
```

This is part of the file which breaks:

```
["Xinhua","ÃœrÃ¼mqi"]
```

**EDIT:** 
No idea why my question is misunderstood. Hopefully this is better formed.

**How should I read this file with Python?**

**[Sample file link](http://www.filedropper.com/countrycity2)** (UTF-16-LE file) containing:

```
["Xinhua","ÃœrÃ¼mqi"]
```

**Why doesn't this code work?**

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16", errors='replace') as data_file:    
    print(data_file.read())
```

Comment: Are you sure you know which line is failing?

Comment: Please delete chunks of text from (a copy of) the file until you find the smallest possible file that produces the problem, and then post a *hex dump* of that smallest possible file.

Comment: Is the encoding big or little endian? Does the file you are reading contain a byte order marker (BOM)?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams/@zwol: the file is failing for this character: "œ" read by Python as `\u0153`. Not sure what more I can make of that...

@Frank it is little endian with a BOM.

Comment: It's not the reading that fails, it's the printing!

Comment: @MarkRansom: Ah that needs another `.encode()` :). Drove me crazy thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception that originally stumped you is because you're running Python inside a terminal emulator (or possibly "console window" is a more familiar term?) that can't display all of the characters in Unicode.  To fix that you need to get yourself a Unicode-capable terminal emulator, and then ensure Python *knows* it's running inside a Unicode-capable terminal emulator.  If you have no idea how to do that, ask a new question on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), specifying your operating system.

My terminal emulator *can* display all of the characters in Unicode, assuming all the necessary fonts are available, and Python knows that, so I can do this and not get an exception:

```
>>> with open("countryCity2.json", "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
...   x = f.read()
... 
>>> print(x)
["Xinhua","ÃœrÃ¼mqi"]
```

However, that is not your only problem. Your input file has had its encoding mangled. `ÃœrÃ¼mqi` is not a sequence of characters that makes sense in any language.  However, it conforms to the characteristic [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) pattern of text that has been converted from a legacy encoding to UTF-8, and then — incorrectly — converted into a Unicode encoding *again*.  We can test this by converting it 1:1 to bytes and seeing if we get a valid UTF-8 byte sequence:

```
>>> print(x.encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8"))
["Xinhua","Ürümqi"]
```

"[Ürümqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cr%C3%BCmqi)" is a real word and would plausibly appear in conjunction with "[Xinhua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinhua_News_Agency)".  Also, if the text weren't mis-converted UTF-8, we would have seen an exception:

```
>>> "Ürümqi".encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0:
  invalid continuation byte
```

So the hypothesis is confirmed.

In a program that had to deal with a great many files whose encodings might or might not have been mangled in this way, I would do something like this:

```
for fname in input_files:
    with open(fname, "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
        contents = f.read()
    try:
        contents = contents.encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8")
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
        pass
    process_file(fname, contents)
```

I am using the [ISO 8859.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding here *not* because the text is or was ever actually in that encoding, but because Python's `iso-8859-1` codec is an identity mapping from characters U+0000..U+00FF to bytes 0x00..0xFF.  (Technically, that means it implements IANA ISO_8859-1:1987 instead of the original ECMA-94:1985 codepage, which left the 0x00..0x1F and 0x7F..0x9F ranges undefined.) That is,

```
>>> "".join(chr(c) for c in range(256)).encode('iso-8859-1') == bytes(range(256))
True
```

Therefore, any time you have binary data that has been mis-converted into Unicode, you can recover the original with `.encode('iso-8859-1')`.

**NOTE:** All code snippets above are Python 3.

Comment: I really appreciate this thorough explanation, wish I could give more upvotes.

Comment: I'm gonna start using Powershell for my Python execution :)

Comment: @zwol: `except UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError`: this generate an error, it is incorrect to use this lign, but it work forme when i use only `except UnicodeEncodeError:`

Comment: @ChediBechikh Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer work on Python3.5 and ignore all maformed caracters,so the objectif is to print the correct caracters with print in the try bloc, and in the block except you can use pass in the block except, or to  print them and to encode them with encode()

```
from codecs import open
with open("C:/test2/trans1", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
for ligne in lines:
    try:
        print(ligne.rstrip())
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print(ligne.rstrip().encode())
```